# When will the TLD .app be publicly available for registration?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar, top-level-domains

My website would be well suited for the `.app` top level domain. I'd like to register the name as soon it's possible.

Is there any information on when it's possible for "normal" people to register and use an `.app` domain?

Any additional info on estimated price or registrars would be appreciated.

Comment: As you probably know, several companies will let you pre-register a .app domain: http://www.1and1.com/app-domain?__lf=newdomains&linkOrigin=new-top-level-domains&linkId=ct.txt.tld.app http://www.instra.com/en/domain-names/newgtld/app-domain-registration/app https://dotanything.co/tlddetail.aspx?tld=APP but there are many companies competing for .app and ICANN has not chosen a winner yet: https://gtldresult.icann.org/applicationstatus/contentionsetdiagram:get_image_stream_event;jsessionid=3321237B1F0B2F20E93E59F16C6B6AA9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.app` TLD became available to register in **May 2018**:

> #### Introducing .app, a more secure home for apps on the web
>
> Today we’re announcing .app, the newest top-level domain (TLD) from Google Registry.
>
> Starting today at 9:00am PDT and through May 7, .app domains are available to register as part of our Early Access Program, where, for an additional fee, you can secure your desired domains ahead of general availability. And then beginning on May 8, .app domains will be available to the general public through your registrar of choice.
>
> https://blog.google/technology/developers/introducing-app-more-secure-home-apps-web/

Comment: FWIW, IANA lists it as "created:      2015-06-25" but it all depends on what "became available" means exactly (starts to resolve on root nameservers? is available for purchase? at which phase? sunrise? EAP? general availability?). You can find the various "launch" dates at https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/program-status/sunrise-claims-periods?search_api_views_fulltext=app&sunrise_open%5Bdate%5D=&sunrise_close%5Bdate%5D=&field_gtld_sunrise_close=2

Answer (score 0):

.app is only a proposed gTLD and as such there is no release date from ICANN yet.